# How to create a infinite nested json and access the same in go lang data structures?

Tags: json, go, data-structures

How to create a infinite nested json and access the same in go lang data structures,

For example below is the sample json with 3 levels, in general it should be dynamic, user can add any children by selecting the value from the dropdown which is populated tree like dropdown on UI.

```
{
        "value": {
            "Id": "1",
            "Text": "abcd",
            "Parent": ""
        },
        "children": [
            {
                "value": {
                    "Id": "2",
                    "Text": "abcd",
                    "Parent": "1"
                },
                "children": [
                    {
                        "value": {
                            "Id": "3",
                            "Text": "abcd",
                            "Parent": "1"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

structures in go: I have created this go data structure but it will access only upto 3 levels based on the above json, can we make this data structure as dynamic where it should handle infinite nested json.

```
 type AutoGenerated struct {
        Value struct {
            ID     string `json:"Id"`
            Text   string `json:"Text"`
            Parent string `json:"Parent"`
        } `json:"value"`
        Children []struct {
            Value struct {
                ID     string `json:"Id"`
                Text   string `json:"Text"`
                Parent string `json:"Parent"`
            } `json:"value"`
            Children []struct {
                Value struct {
                    ID     string `json:"Id"`
                    Text   string `json:"Text"`
                    Parent string `json:"Parent"`
                } `json:"value"`
            } `json:"children"`
        } `json:"children"`
    }
```

Note: we can add n number of parents and n number of children, is this possible in Go data structures?

can you suggest best and easy way to implement this?

How can we add/delete/edit any parent or child? (The above json example will come from UI) ? To add/delete/edit any parent or child which json structure or id needed?

Answer (score 4):

You can use recursive structures in Go to represent this json (by recursive, I mean that `Level` contains a `[]Level`):

```
type Value struct {
    ID     string
    Text   string
    Parent string
}

type Level struct {
    Value    Value `json:"value"`
    Children []Level
}
```

Given the json you listed as the string `j`, I can now unmarshal it as follows:

```
var root Level
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(j), &root)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(root)
fmt.Println(root.Children[0])
fmt.Println(root.Children[0].Children[0])
```

This outputs:

```
{{1 abcd } [{{2 abcd 1} [{{3 abcd 1} []}]}]}
{{2 abcd 1} [{{3 abcd 1} []}]}
{{3 abcd 1} []}
```

[Go playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/Z7mNkX2sxuI)

Comment: For ex: from the UI, if we want to add any new children, how to add it to the existing structure? based on which key we need to update?

Comment: What UI? You just provided json, nothing else. If you want to add a child to a given parent, iterate through the tree until you find the value with matching ID and add the child to the slice of children.

Comment: how can we add the child? Any append functions are available?, Sorry i was newbie to golang :(

Comment: Appending to a slice is just `Children = append(Children, newChild)`. I recommend you take the Go tour, this is covered in the [Appending to a slice](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/15) section.

Comment: Modifying the tree is just a combination of iterating over it and adding/removing/modifying children. This is unrelated to parsing the json and is technically a separate question. However, it is such a basic use of Go that it's strongly recommended that you take the Go tour, we won't write that code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to @marc, you can combine these two struct `Value` & `Level` in a single structure. Like AutoGenerated one, you only need to use [ ]Level as Children.

```
type Level struct {
    Value struct {
        ID     string
        Text   string
        Parent string
    } `json:"value"`
    Children []Level
}
```

See in <kbd>[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/IbyIWIXz7Ta)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Marc's data structure, a simple `add`:

```
func (l *Level) Add(path,Id,Text string) error {
    if path=="" {
        l.Children = append(l.Children, Level{ Value: Value{Id,Text,l.Value.ID} })
        return nil
    }
    x:=strings.SplitN(path,".",2)
    name,remain:=x[0],""
    if len(x)>1 {
        remain = x[1]
    }

    for i:=range l.Children {
        if l.Children[i].Value.ID == name {
            return l.Children[i].Add(remain,Id,Text)
        }
    }
    return errors.New("Not found")
}

func main() {
    var root Level
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(j), &root)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(root)
    fmt.Println(root.Children[0])
    fmt.Println(root.Children[0].Children[0])
    fmt.Println(root.Add("2.3","4","xxx"))
    fmt.Println(root)
}
```

Remove and modify would be mostly the same.

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/7sWRJ-9EQSv

Comment: will that accepts unlimited tree like structures, like a branch may have any number of nodes.

Comment: could you please explain add function logic?